# Interactive message

Tags: slack, slack-api

I would like to create Slack a interactive messages with a behaviour like:

[image]

The message is published via an incoming webhook, when the user clicks on *Approve* I POST a text message to the *response_url*.

Unfortunately the text message replace completely the original message and I get an ugly *(edited)* flag besides the posted message. I would like to replace only the buttons of the original message. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that I need to use *replace_original* attribute (see [doc](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#updating_message_response)), taking the entire original message and replacing the buttons section with a text section.

Comment: do you have a simple example of how this works? beent rying to figure it otu using the doc but still no luck

Comment: Any example? I've been trying this but not luck either?